# Oracle Web APP 11g/Oracle NCA Scripting in LoadRunner: correlating icx_ticket

Tags: performance-testing, oracleforms, loadrunner

I have this function to correlate icx_ticket in a LoadRunner script:

```
web_reg_save_param("WCSParam11", 
    "LB=icx_ticket='", 
    "RB/IC='resp", 
    "Ord=1", 
    "Search=Body", 
    LAST);
```

The parameter is not being captured and I am consistently getting this error.

Action.c(127): Error -26377: No match found for the requested parameter "WCSParam11". Check whether the requested boundaries exist in the response data. Also, if the data you want to save exceeds 10240 bytes, use web_set_max_html_param_len to increase the parameter size      [MsgId: MERR-26377]
Action.c(127): Notify: Saving Parameter "WCSParam11 = ".

I can see in the data returned by the server icx_ticket appears as:

Action.c(79):     GET /OA_HTML/txkObjectTag.js HTTP/1.1\r\n
Action.c(79):     Referer: http://erpuat.safaricom.net:8010/forms/frmservlet?appletmode=nonforms&HTMLpageTit
Action.c(79):     le=&HTMLpreApplet=&code=oracle/apps/fnd/formsClient/FormsLauncher.class&width=400&height=3
Action.c(79):     00&archive=/OA_JAVA/oracle/apps/fnd/jar/fndforms.jar,/OA_JAVA/oracle/apps/fnd/jar/fndforms
Action.c(79):     i18n.jar,/OA_JAVA/oracle/apps/fnd/jar/fndewt.jar,/OA_JAVA/oracle/apps/fnd/jar/fndswing.jar
Action.c(79):     ,/OA_JAVA/oracle/apps/fnd/jar/fndbalishare.jar,/OA_JAVA/oracle/apps/fnd/jar/fndaol.jar,/OA
Action.c(79):     _JAVA/oracle/apps/fnd/jar/fndctx.jar,/OA_JAVA/oracle/apps/fnd/jar/fndlist.jar&jinit_applet
Action.c(79):     cache=off&gp15=icx_ticket&gv15=Vg4ifaWvXEHX1nnuRaKLlg..&gp2=resp_app&gv2=SQLGL&gp3=resp&gv
Action.c(79):     3=GENERAL_LEDGER_SUPER_USER&gp4=sec_group&gv4=STANDARD&gp5=function&gv5=GLXJEPST&gp6=other
Action.c(79):     _params&gv6=&gp7=jsp_agent&gv7=http%3A%2F%2Ferpuat.safaricom.net%3A8010%2FOA_HTML%2F&gp13=
Action.c(79):     dbc&gv13=ERPUAT\r\n

Kindly assist me to correctly capture and save the icx_ticket parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As from my experience you will not able to correlate any value in **ORACLE**.

For saving the dynamic value which comes from server you can use

```
nca_edit_get_text("Field_Name",Variable_Name);
```

Here Field name is the name of the field where this value is present/display and varable mane is the variable you create for storing the data.

```
lr_save_string(Variable_Name, "Any_Name");
```

After that you can save your variable into load-runner variable using above function.

Answer (score 0):

> As from my experience you will not able to correlate any value in ORACLE.

You have very limited experience then.

If a Value is returned then it can be captured.  Here we have the example of an autocorrelated variable not being captured.   One must first ask if the recommended autocorrelation left boundary and right boundary conditions are optimal?  If not, then tune them to be more robust - this requires that the user have manual correlation skills to address the issue   No manual correlation skills then "No joy" on a solution.

Next, let's look at process items that are very commonly paired with a failing autocorrelation, does the script include active examination of expected results from each and every request and then does the script branch execution when the expected result fails to appear.   There is a very high statistical correlation between no check on expected results and a failed LoadRunner variable autocorrelation, on the order of greater than 95%.